# What's wrong with this input ? dropdown arrow doesn't show

Tags: android, android-studio, material-design

Peace programmers!
I'm trying to learn android developlment with kotlin and when
I'm using android studio and I have a problem which is the input doesn't show correcty [dropdown arrow] and also when I run it the app closes how can I solve it, thanks

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:layout_margin="20dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Currency Converter"
        android:textSize="38dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/purple_700"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/guideline2"
        />
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".6"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/from"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="From"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textview"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/from"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        style="@style/Widget.Material3.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
        >

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="American Dollar"
        android:inputType="none"/>

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: If the app closes when you run it, you need to look in the logcat tab to find the error message and stack trace.

Comment: I checked it, the error is in the text field but I didn't find it because it is the same as in material design

Comment: Put the full stack trace and relevant code in the question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This is all the code that I have